# Deriving the PDF of a function of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ and $T_1, \ldots, T_m$ be independent random variables following exponential distributions with parameters $\lambda_X, \lambda_T$, respectively. Let

$$
T_{\rho} = T_1 + \ldots + T_m
$$

so that $T_{\rho} \sim \text{Gamma}(m, \lambda_T)$. Finally, define

$$
\rho(X, T) := \frac{Xm}{T_{\rho}}
$$

I want to find the PDF (and the CDF) of $\rho$. I assumed the best course of action was to find the CDF and then compute the PDF by derivation. Now, if $F_{\rho}$ denotes the CDF of $\rho$,

$$
\begin{align*}
    F_{\rho}(y) &= P\left[ \frac{Xm}{T_{\rho}} \leq y \right] \\ 
                &= P \left[ X \leq \frac{yT_{\rho}}{m} \right]  \\ 
                &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} P(X \leq \frac{yt}{m})f_{T_{\rho}}(t) ~ dt
             \\ &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( 1-\exp(-\lambda_X \frac{yt}{m})
             \right) \left( \frac{\lambda_{T}^m t^{m-1}\exp(-t\lambda_{T})}{(m-1)!} \right) ~ dt \\ 
             &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^+}  
             \left( \frac{\lambda_{T}^m t^{m-1}\exp(-t\lambda_{T})}{(m-1)!}
             \right) ~ dt - \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} \left( \frac{\lambda_{T}^m
             t^{m-1}\exp(-t\lambda_{T})\exp(-\lambda_X \frac{yt}{m})}{(m-1)!} \right) ~ dt \\ 
             &= 1 - \frac{\lambda_T^{m}}{(m-1)!} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+}
             t^{m-1}e^{-t\lambda_T - \lambda_X \frac{yt}{m}} ~ dt \\ 
             &= 1 - \frac{\lambda_T^{m}}{(m-1)!} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+}
             t^{m-1}e^{-t \left( \lambda_T + \frac{y\lambda_X}{m}\right) } ~ dt \\ 
             &= 1 - \frac{\lambda_T^{m}e^{\lambda_T + \frac{y\lambda_X}{m}}}{(m-1)!} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+}
             t^{m-1}e^{-t} ~ dt \\ 
             &= 1 - \frac{\lambda_T^{m}e^{\lambda_T +
             \frac{y\lambda_X}{m}}}{(m-1)!} m!
\end{align*}
$$

I have not been able to confirm that this solution is correct. Is this the correct approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but I think the computation can be simplified.

Let $$F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_X x}, \quad x \ge 0$$ be the CDF of $X$.  Then clearly, the variable $$Y = \lambda_X X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1),$$ and similarly,
$$S = \lambda_T T_\rho \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(m,1),$$ hence
$$\rho = \frac{m X}{T_\rho} = \frac{m \lambda_T}{\lambda_X} \frac{Y}{S}.$$  This lets us work with $Y$ and $S$ which have simpler densities since their rate parameters are now $1$.  To this end, let $W = Y/S$.  Then
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[W > w] &= \Pr[Y > wS] \\
&= \int_{s=0}^\infty \Pr[Y > ws]f_S(s) \, ds \\
&= \int_{s=0}^\infty e^{-ws} \frac{s^{m-1} e^{-s}}{\Gamma(m)} \, ds \\
&= \int_{s=0}^\infty \frac{s^{m-1} e^{-(w+1)s}}{\Gamma(m)} \, ds.
\end{align}$$
The integrand *almost* looks like a gamma density, but there should be a factor of $(w+1)^m$.  So we put it in:
$$\Pr[W > w] = \frac{1}{(w+1)^m} \int_{s=0}^\infty \frac{(w+1)^m s^{m-1} e^{-(w+1)s}}{\Gamma(m)} \, ds = \frac{1}{(w+1)^m},$$
since now the integrand is the density of a gamma distributed random variable with shape parameter $m$ and rate $w+1$, so it integrates to $1$.  So now we have the survival function of $W$, which has the support $W \ge 0$.  Consequently, letting $c = m\lambda_T/\lambda_X$ be a constant function of the given parameters,
$$\Pr[\rho > w] = \Pr[cW > w] = \Pr[W > w/c] = \frac{1}{(w/c + 1)^m},$$
from which we readily obtain the CDF
$$F_\rho(w) = 1 - \frac{1}{(w/c + 1)^m}, \quad w \ge 0,$$
and the PDF
$$f_\rho(w) = \frac{m}{c(w/c+1)^{m+1}} = \frac{\lambda_X}{\lambda_T} \left( \frac{\lambda_X}{m\lambda_T} w + 1 \right)^{-(m+1)}, w \ge 0.$$
Thus, $\rho$ follows a [Lomax or Pareto Type II distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomax_distribution) with shape $m$ and scale $c$.

Comment: I am giving your solution a good look. In the meantime, I should mention that I found a solution that seems to be different to yours---surely I am doing something wrong. I'll edit my question to include it.

Comment: Forgot to say, thanks for the very detailed answer.

Comment: @lafinur The result you obtained can't be correct, because as $y \to \infty$, you should have $F_\rho(y) \to 1$, but your function does not do this.  Your error is in the step where you go from the third to last to the second to last line.  It appears as if you tried to factor out a term of the form $e^{Kt}$ for a constant $K$, but $e^{Kt} \ne e^K e^t$.  If you perform a variable substitution of the form $$u = \left(\lambda_T + \frac{y \lambda_X}{m}\right) t,$$ then you must also take into account its effect on the factor $t^{m-1}$ in the integrand.

Comment: What a silly error I made. Thanks for pointing it out!!

Comment: @lafinur You are most welcome.  One of the problem-solving strategies I try to use as much as possible is to consolidate variables or constants, to try to reduce the complexity of notation so that each step is clearer to understand.  Afterward, I can "unpack" the notation.

Comment: Yeah, to be honest that was a pretty impressive trick. Made everything much simpler and elegant. Will definitely keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: I don't mean to be insistent---in full appreciation of your answer, I'm still trying to work my own way through the problem, to learn math on the way. Correcting the mistake you pointed out, I got (after the third to last formula in my question): $F_{\rho}(y) = 1 - \frac{\lambda_T^{m}}{(m-1)!} \left( \lambda_T +
             \frac{y\lambda_X}{m} \right)^{-m}\Gamma(m)$

The derivative is similar to what you have, giving $\lambda_X \lambda_T^{m}\left( 
\lambda_T + y\lambda_X/m \right)^{-(m+1)}$.

Comment: @lafinur Since $m$ is a positive integer, $\Gamma(m)/(m-1)! = 1$, hence your expression becomes $$F_\rho(y) = 1 -\lambda_T^m \left(\lambda_T + \frac{y \lambda_X}{m}\right)^m = 1 - \left(1 + \frac{\lambda_X}{m \lambda_T} y \right)^{-m}.$$  This is equivalent to my result, with $c = m\lambda_T/\lambda_X$.  Similarly, with your PDF, writing $$\lambda_X \lambda_T^m = \frac{\lambda_X}{\lambda_T} \cdot \lambda_T^{m+1}$$ and combining this with the other factor, should give you the same expression as I obtained.

Comment: That's clarifying. Glad to see my much less elegant approach led to something. Once again, thanks for all four help and your excellent answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to revive this but can we truly say that rho follows a Lomax distribution? It has an added 1/m factor in the first term of the expression that is raised to the power of $-(m+1)$

Comment: @lafinur The shape parameter is $m$ and the scale parameter is $c = m\lambda_T/\lambda_X$.  The fact that both parameters contain a factor of $m$ is immaterial; it is still Pareto distributed.  For instance, if I say a variable $X$ is normally distributed with mean $5\theta + 1$ and variance $3\theta^2$, that's just a particular choice of parameters.  For the choice $\theta = 1$, that would give you a mean of $6$ and variance of $3$.  Similarly, if you choose $m = 5, \lambda_X = 7, \lambda_T = 1$, then you get $\rho$ is Pareto with shape $5$ and scale $5/7$.